# Regex syntax for finding second digit group OR start of search in string in python

Tags: python, regex-group

I am trying to use `Regex` in Python to find the 2nd group of numbers in strings with the format:

```
"123= TEXTINCAPS('Example One',$,$,10.,$);"
```

The format can also come with longer digit groups or groups with a value below 1.0:

```
"123= TEXTINCAPS('Example Two',$,$,0.2521,$);"
```

The results I expect to get are:

```
10
```

and

```
0.2521
```

When I use the online tester to find '(\d+)' it finds the two groups of numbers (i.e. 123 and 10), but it marks both of them in the Match Information panel as "Group 1".

My questions are:

1) How can I select for the 2nd group only to be returned?

2) Is it instead better to start the regex from a certain point along the string like the '(' character? I'm not sure how to do that even after reading up on it.

Comment: You say, "I am trying to use Regex in Python..." Do you mean "trying to use regular expressions" which by default implies the `re` library, or do you mean "trying to use the experimental `regex` library"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just capture both groups of digits in your pattern separated by any non-digits:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "123= TEXTINCAPS('Example One',$,$,10.,$);"
>>> m = re.match(r'(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)', s)
>>> m.group(1)
123
>>> m.group(2)
10
```

Comment: a further question directly related:
From what I understand m = re.match gives a boolean value, but is m.group(num) an int or a string? My aim is also to convert the number to a float type.

Answer (score 1):

Just *find all* numbers then choose the second!

So with your first example:

```
e1 = "123= TEXTINCAPS('Example One',$,$,10.,$);"
```

we can just do:

```
re.findall("\d*\.*\d+", e1)
```

which gives:

```
["123", "10"]
```

And for:

```
e2 = "123= TEXTINCAPS('Example Two',$,$,0.2521,$);"
```

we get:

```
['123', '0.2521']
```

---

So obviously, if you just want the second index, just take the second element by doing the calls as above with `re.findall(...)[1]`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Ha! Missed the case for single digits... I think it should work now.

Comment: Yeah, might be right for the OP's cases. Try `"10..20"`, though, denoting the range of the integers from 10 to 20, so I'd expect `["10", "20"]`.

Comment: Hmm, I guess `["10.", ".20"]` would also be a somewhat reasonable result. But not `["10..20"]`.

Answer (score 1):

> You can use Positive Lookbehind (?<=,) :

```
import re
pattern=r'(?<=,)[0-9.]+'
text="""123= TEXTINCAPS('Example Two',$,$,0.2521,$);
"123= TEXTINCAPS('Example One',$,$,10.,$);"""
match=re.finditer(pattern,text)
for find in match:
    print(find.group())
```

output:

```
0.2521
10.
```

Regex Explanation:

> ```
> Positive Lookbehind (?<=,)
> ```

```
Assert that the Regex below matches
, matches the character , literally (case sensitive)
```

> `Match a single character present in the list below [0-9.]+`

```
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

> `0-9`

```
 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your format is always that of a function-call, you might skip the regular expression entirely and split on the commas:

```
line = "123= TEXTINCAPS('Example One',$,$,10.,$);"
print(line.split(',')[-2])
```

(Note: prefer the negative indexing since there might be one or more commas in the leading quoted-string.)